# Generate a random number upon clicking registration button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JavaScript to try and generate a random number of 15 digits when a user clicks a registration button, and display it in a `div` element. I have tried a lot of things, but can't get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" action="form_profile.html" method="POST" name="register" class="wizard-big">
    <!--<h1>Account</h1>-->
    <fieldset>
        <!--<h2>Account Information</h2>-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                    <select type="text" class="form-control required" name="salutation">
                    <option value="">Salutation</option>
                    <option value="1">Mr</option>
                        <option value="2">Ms</option>
                        </select>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>First Name *</label>-->
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" class="form-control required" id="fname" name="fname">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Middle Name </label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" id="mname" name="mname">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Last Name *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname">
                </div>




                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Place of Birth" class="form-control required" id="pob" name="pob">
                    </div>  

                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group" id="data_1">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control required"  placeholder="Date of Birth" id="dob" name="dob">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Qualification" id="qualification" name="qualification">
            </div>


                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Graduation" id="pg" name="pg">
                </div>  

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group" id="data_1">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Post graduation Year" id="pgy" name="pgy">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Graduation *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Graduation" id="graduation" name="graduation">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group" id="data_1">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Graduation Year" id="gy" name="gy">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Schooling *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Schooling" id="schooling" name="schooling">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group" id="data_1">
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Schooling Year" id="sy" name="sy">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Religion *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Religion" id="religion" name="religion">
                </div>  
                 <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Caste *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Caste" id="caste" name="caste">
                </div> 
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Subcaste *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subcaste" id="subcaste" name="subcaste">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Family Name *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Family Name" id="familyname" name="familyname">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Father Name *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Father Name" id="fathername" name="fathername">
                </div>      
                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Mother Name *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mother Name" id="mothername" name="mothername">
                </div> 
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Brothers *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Brothers" id="brothers" name="brothers">
                </div>      
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <!--<label>Sisters *</label>-->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sisters" id="sisters" name="sisters">
                </div> 


                <!--<div  class="col-sm-12 form-group" id="recaptcha_widget">
                    <div class="required">
                      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc4vP4SAAAAABjhRjyoMguw66mNSBgdpBF398AG"></div>
                   </div>
                  <?php //include("js/captcha.php");?>
                </div> -->

                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <br><button style="width:100%" type="submit" id="insertncontinue"  class="btn btn-success">Save and Generate Vault No</button>
                </div><!--==== End col-sm-4 form-group==-->
                  <div id="demo"></div>
                <!--<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <button style="width:100%" type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Save and Continue</button>
                </div>--><!--==== End col-sm-4 form-group==--> 
                <!--<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                    <a href="#"><button style="width:100%" type="button"  class="btn btn-success">Edit</button></a>
                </div>--><!--==== End col-sm-4 form-group==--> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                        <i class="" style="font-size: 180px;color: #e5e5e5 "></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //execute's the function on click
    $("#insertncontinue").click(function(e){

        var status = $('form')[0].checkValidity();
        if(status){
            /*jquery to call the url requested 
            and parse the data in json*/
            $.ajax({
                url: "form_profile.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#form").serialize(),
                async: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                /*Give out the alert box
                to display the results*/ 
                success: function (json){
                    if(json.error){
                        alert(json.error_msg);
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }else{
                         $("#insertncontinue").click(function(e){
                            document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML =  Math.floor(Math.random()*1E16);
                        }
                        alert("DATA ADDED SCCCESSFULLY!");
                        $('#form').submit();
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: use `Math.random()` for this.

Comment: what error or issue you are facing?

Comment: use `Math.floor(Math.random()*1E16)` for 15 digit random number.

Comment: sir..!! nothing is been displayed is directs me to a page containing this whole code..!!

Comment: @parth sir...okay ill try sir

Comment: you never called myFunction

Comment: soo...please sir how can i solve the problem..!!??

Comment: Where is the element with ID "demo"? It's not shown in the code you have provided. Are any errors logged in your browser console? Which browser are you experiencing problems in? Can you use your browser developer tools to see if the call to form_profile.php is returning successfully? as it is currently coded the random number will *only* be generated on a successful response (the code is within the "success" callback).

Comment: @pwdst sir...i have updated the code plz  check it out and help me out..!!

Comment: and the form_profile.php is succesfully executed and showing alert "REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL  but javascript part is not executing..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes in Your HTML Code
remove `action="form_profile.html"`  from form because you using ajax for submit form,
change 
`type="submit"` as `type="button"`

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#insertncontinue").click(function () {

            var randomnumber = Math.random().toString().slice(-15);
            $("#generatenumber").html(randomnumber );

           // this is ur randomnumber see at console or you can alert it.
            console.log(randomnumber);
           //  all remaining code as it is... 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add html div  inside in form `<div id="generatenumber"></div>`

Try it.